# Export unicode data from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I have some data in one of my mysql table stored as utf8. The data is some japanese text. I need to export it to excel. Could you tell how to do it?
Exporting by `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` returns some plain text file. I'm not sure how to read it back in excel so that japanese character would show properly

Thanks
Nayn

Comment: Have you tried? Excel should recognize it, or you should be able to choose a charset during importing. If it doesn't work, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the text file retains the data as is. It is just that if we open directly in excel, it misinterprets the character encoding for the file. I opened it using notepad and saved in encoding as 'utf8'. next time when i opened it in excel it showed the characters properly.
Thanks
Nayn

Answer (score 1):

Just provide CHARACTER SET charset_name when you do SELECT INTO OUTFILE as export_option http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html and you will be fine. If you will have some troubles with direct opening with Excel, have it import data using universal filter *.* in Open dialog. It will then let you select file encoding to import.

Comment: mysql> select @@version; --> 4.1.10-log. I think it does not support this option. It is giving error.

Comment: @Nayn: Might be brute force, but why not install a more current version of MySQL to a dev box & import a MySQL dump from the Production system to see if FractalizeR's suggestion will work?